# Setting Cookies in iFrame not setting despite samesite and secure

Tags: cookies, iframe

Even though I set `samesite=none` and `secure`, I cannot set the cookie on an iFrame from the server nor in JavaScript.

A number of [stack questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025587/prevent-chrome-from-disabling-cookies-in-iframe) talk [about Aug 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151183/cookie-not-being-set-in-iframe) being when Chrome started requiring both of the above settings.

This is fine, but even when I attempt to use JS as below:

```js
document.cookie = "my_cookie4=cookie_value4; secure; samesite=none";
```

I can't seem to set a cookie in the iframe. I'm using Chrome's Application inspector to see what cookies are being applied with what settings and I'm setting it in JS to bypass servers.

I'm using a locally signed+accepted SSL for `https`, but I doubt that is the issue. But just in case:

1. Website is: `https://localhost:4000`
2. iFrame is: `https://test-domain.partner.lvh.me:3000`

If I visit the iFrame's URL directly everything works perfectly as expected. samesite is none, secure is present, etc.